# Get Orientation of SCNNode Swift

Tags: swift, rotation, scenekit, skphysicsbody, scnnode

I am slowly getting frustrated because I don't seem to find a way to get the current orientation of my `SCNNode` object.

I am trying to fly a kite which should rotate slightly to the right when I fly right and vice versa. I am doing the rotation by `physicsBody.applyTorque` every time I fly to one side, since changing the `eulerAngles` of the Node itself does not work properly (always resets to 0).

The problem I am facing is that every time I print `kiteNode.orientation/eulerAngles` or any other, they print `(0,0,0)`. On the other hand when I print `kiteNode.physicsBody.angularVelocity` it gives me the right values.

Is there any way to print the current angle and not only the angular velocity of the `physicsBody`? Or how does one get the current orientation of the `SCNNode`?

Code:

```swift
func rollKite() {
   // SIDES ROLLING
   if _gameSCNScene.touchingRightButton {
       self.ballNode.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(0, 0, 1, 0.1), asImpulse: true)
   } else if _gameSCNScene.touchingLeftButton {
       self.ballNode.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(0, 0, -1, 0.1), asImpulse: true)
   } else {
       // This part does not work since the eulerAngles are always (0,0,0)
       self.ballNode.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(0, 0, -10*self.ballNode.eulerAngles.z, 0.1), asImpulse: true)
   }
   // this works:
   print("Quat Kite: \(self.ballNode.physicsBody?.angularVelocity)")
   // this doesn't:
   print("Euler Kite: \(self.ballNode.eulerAngles)")
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!